# set a default value for select field in Laravel using collective form builder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I have a select field in my form for selecting admin roles.I need to set a default value for that select field like 'Select Role'.I am using Laravel 5.2 and collective form builder class.here is my code

```
{!! Form::select('role_id',App\Role::orderBy('name')->lists('label','id'),$roleId,array('class'=>'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12','id'=>'role_id')) !!}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third argument is a default for select list, so `$roleId` should contain default role ID in this case.

If it doesn't work, you should check what `$roleId` contains and also look into HTML generated by `Form::select` clause to find a problem.

**Update**

To add `Select Role` default value, do this before `Form::select` clause:

```
<?php
    $rolesList = App\Role::orderBy('name')->lists('label','id');
    $rolesList[0] = 'Select Role';
    ksort($rolesList); // Will resort list.
?>
```

Comment: Here $roleId  is null in ma case.But i dont have a null valued array in this list

Comment: `<select id="role_id" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="role_id">
<option value="2">Admin</option>
<option value="1">Super Admin</option>
</select>` this my html

Comment: So, you should check why it's null. Or you could use default for `$roleId`. For example, if you want default role ID to be `1`, you can change `$roleId` to `$roleId or 1` or to `$roleId ? $roleId : 1`

Comment: Its working properly.Actually i need a default value like `<option value="0">Select Role</option>'